# Amplify Backend gives error The user does not have permissions to create triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

[image]

Hi I get this error when i try and create an Amplify Backend.

Seems to be realated to not being able to create lambda functions

```
aws lambda --profile haniq-main create-function --function-name my-function --zip-file fileb://function.zip --handler index.handler --runtime nodejs18.x --role arn:aws:iam::640766513655:role/lambda-ex


An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: None
```

Answer (score 0):

Well my account was blocked internally :)